# wb.Save() Saving to Wrong Location

Tags: python, excel, save, win32com

The below code is saving the file in my documents folder not the test folder were I would like it saved too. It also asks If I would like to overwrite the test file already in the documents folder.

How can I get this just to save in original path and overwrite current file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import pyautogui
import os
import os, os.path
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os.path
import shutil
import glob
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client
from xlrd import *
import csv
import sys
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook



    FilePath = r'C:\Users\bands\Test\Test.xlsm'
    FileName = 'Test.xlsm'
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(FilePath), False, True, None, 'Password')
    # Insert Text
    ws = wb.Worksheets('Rolling Calendar View')
    ws.Range('C19').Value = "87"
    ws.Range('C21').Value = "87"
    wb.SaveAs(FileName)
    xl.Application.Run("Refresh")
    xl.Application.Run("EMAIL")
    xl.Application.Quit()
    del xl
```

Comment: `wb.Save()` perhaps?

Comment: Tried this and causes same issue.

Comment: Well it can't be the same issue. `SaveAs` with just a filename is not equivalent to `Save`. Is it a different issue?

Comment: wb.SaveAs(FileName) and wb.Save() result in the same outcome as described.

Comment: It is highly unlikely for `wb.Save` to save in your Documents folder, based on the code you've provided, namely that its path is `C:\Users\bands\Test\Test.xlsm`.

Comment: I agree it makes no sense. Could something be imported incorrectly causing it to default to the documents folder? Let me edit the post with everything imported. Also is the way that it is being opened perhaps taking it out of the folder some how?

Comment: `wb.SaveAs(FileName)` should be `wb.SaveAs(FilePath)`? Also you are opening the workbook readonly (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open): 3rd argument = True, so `Save()` is unlikely to succeed.